# What can cause MEMORYCLERK_SOSNODE clerk gradually taking available memory in SQL Server 2019 CU14?

Tags: sql-server, memory-leaks

One of our production server is crashing after every few weeks due to low memory. We found that the instance memory is taken by MEMORYCLERK_SOSNODE clerk. When this clerk gradually use available memory, the plan cache becomes small and SQL engine starts compiling and re-compiling plans frequently. Also, the page life expectancy fluctuates a lot.
Memory clerk size

Please click below links to see the screenshot. I'm not able to post it as a picture here as I don't have enough reputation points in stackoverflow yet.

[Memory assigned for other memory clerk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvJPd.png)

[top 5 memory clerk size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYCrR.jpg)

Now, I found that the Microsoft has put fix for this clerk gradually taking available memory in their CU11 and same fix they put in CU15 (Not sure if they actually fixed it)

Fix in SQL 2019 CU11
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5003249-cumulative-update-11-for-sql-server-2019-657b2977-a0f1-4e1f-8b93-8c2ca8b6bef5#bkmk_13990055

Fix in SQL 2019 CU15
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5008996-cumulative-update-15-for-sql-server-2019-4b6a8ee9-1c61-482d-914f-36e429901fb6

Both fix says, it can cause by using spatial index. We are not using it at all. Since Microsoft has KB article says they fixed it in CU11 and then again in CU15. I'm pretty sure, something is wrong here.

Can anyone help me narrow down the problem here?

Thank you.

Comment: How much physical memory? What is max server memory? What is the sum of data size? Do you see this only on a single system, or does it also happen on a system where you could test CU15 (or CU16)? (Note that not all fixes in a given CU always make it to the KB.) Also "not sure if they actually fixed it" - sometimes you can have multiple causes for a bug or condition, but you can't fix them all at once (or a second one doesn't become obvious until you've eliminated the first one). Look how many times they fixed UDF inlining.

Comment: ^ context: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4538581-fix-scalar-udf-inlining-issues-in-sql-server-2019-f52d3759-a8b7-a107-1ab9-7fbee264dd5d

Comment: Box has 24GB and we have set 12GB max for SQL Instance. Data size is 36GB. No We don't see this in any other box. No, we don't have any other box with CU15 or 16. We can test in test environment but we don't know how to since we don't have similar load on it.

Comment: Why only 12GB for SQL? Ideally, the ratio is much higher because a SQL Server instance is isolated on a box and no other processes should need anywhere near as much memory. Could you try with 21GB or so for SQL Server's max server memory setting?

Comment: And I suggest making it a priority to develop a way to test real-ish workload on a non-production machine. There are many tools and scripts out there for this kind of thing.

Comment: Do you have trans replication running on that box?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/releases/sqlserver-2019/cumulativeupdate19 there is also a fix for the memory leak:
2068768 - "Fixes a gradual memory leak in the SQL Server process (the high usage under MEMORYCLERK_SOSNODE) caused by the Log Reader Agent in transactional replication."